# How to tell that the field "Name" is composed of other fields in the Contact object?

Tags: lightning, contact, standard-objects

The Contact object has a field called "Name", the field is apparently composed of three other fields, "Salutation", "First Name" and "Last Name", which don't show at all under Contacts > Fields & Relationships in the Object Manager (Technically, they *do* show [in the classic version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6G0d.png) albeit they can't be modified as far as I know.

They also appear [in the field reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Contact.htm).

How should I be able to tell this is how it works? I frankly found out by sheer luck while trying to make an API call for lastName, which I didn't expect to work. I assume there ought to be some place in Lightning Experience I can look into to find things like API handles for those records, am I just not seeing it?

Answer (score 1):

This may be of help - [Salesforce Object Reference for Contact](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm)

> Name
>
> Type string
>
> Properties  Filter, Group, Sort
>
> Description Concatenation of FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, and Suffix up to 203 characters, including whitespaces.

Note that the field is not createable.